# Selenium hidden file upload with JavaScipt

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

I've the following input form, where I would like to upload a .txt file with my test script:

```
    <ol>
        <li id="EA-Blk-Invite-Text1">
            Create and save a text file in a specific format as explained <a href="" class="deadlink" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".companyBulkInvite .sampleCSV"><span class="preview mln" data-action="sampleCSV">here</span></a>
        </li>
        <li id="EA-Blk-Invite-Text2">
            <p>Upload the text file as prepared above</p>
        </li>
    </ol>
    <div class="fileuploadArea clearfix pull-left" id="EA-Blk-Invite-Upload">
        <div class="ChooseFile" data-flu="name2" data-target="[preview-container-text-bulk]" data-file-template="uploadCard" data-error-target="[data-upload-error-text-bulk]" data-type="txt" data-context="bulkImport" id="EA-Blk-Invite-Fileup">
            <button class="custom-style-fileIOBtn">Choose File</button>
            <input type="file" class="fileCntr" name="fileinput2" style="display:none;">
        </div>
        <div class="customLogo phn" id="EA-Blk-Invite-Filetext">
            <h5>No file selected</h5>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix previewCntr" preview-container-text-bulk="">
    </div>

    <div class="clearfix col-xs-12 errorMessage-Main" id="EA-Blk-Invite-Errmsg">
        <div data-upload-error-text-bulk="" class="errorMessage"></div>
    </div>
        <div class="btnCntr pull-right">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default cancelUpload" id="EA-Blk-Invite-Can-Btn">Cancel</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary importFile" id="EA-Blk-Invite-Send-Btn">Send Invitations</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

I used a JS Executor to make the input element interactable. I can upload the file - according to my console log - however, I cannot submit the form. I get a 'File is required' error.

```
//Upload file with user's email list
        await koreLib.sleep(3000);
        await driver.executeScript('document.getElementById("EA-Blk-Invite-Fileup").style = "inline"');
        console.log(`\nElement is visible`)

        await koreLib.sleep(3000);
        await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.className('fileCntr')));
        console.log(`\nElement is located`);

        await driver.findElement(By.className('fileCntr')).sendKeys('C:\\Users\\...\\bulkInvite.txt');

        console.log(`\nFile upload success`)

        //Press submit button    
        await koreLib.sleep(6000);
        await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.xpath("//button[@id='EA-Blk-Invite-Send-Btn']")));
        await driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@id='EA-Blk-Invite-Send-Btn']")).click();
        console.log(`\nSubmit button pressed`)
```

When I upload the file manually, the following section is created, however, not with my script.

```
<div class="fileuploadArea clearfix pull-left" id="EA-Blk-Invite-Upload">
        <div class="ChooseFile" data-flu="name2" data-target="[preview-container-text-bulk]" data-file-template="uploadCard" data-error-target="[data-upload-error-text-bulk]" data-type="txt" data-context="bulkImport" id="EA-Blk-Invite-Fileup">
            <button class="custom-style-fileIOBtn">Choose File</button>
            <input type="file" class="fileCntr" name="fileinput2" style="display:none;">
        </div>
        <div class="customLogo phn hidden" id="EA-Blk-Invite-Filetext">
            <h5>No file selected</h5>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix previewCntr" preview-container-text-bulk=""><div>
<div class="col-xs-7 fileName">bulkInvite.txt</div>
<div class="col-xs-3 progressBar">
```

What am I doing wrong? Which element should be used for the upload if not

```
<input type="file" class="fileCntr" name="fileinput2" style="display:none;">
```

Thanks!